# Trouble Linking JQuery to HTML with correct order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been having so many problems with getting my JQuery to load properly. I have looked at youtube videos and scoured Google but nothing seems to work :(

The most common problem with JQuery not being loaded properly is that people load the js file BEFORE the JQuery, but I have loaded it in the correct order and I am still having problems.

Before, I was able to run my feature that used JQuery only locally, but now even that isn't working.

Here is my index.html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    
    <head>  
        
            <title> Website </title>
            <link rel = "stylesheet" href="style.css" /> <!-- Link to css --> 
           
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="script.js"> </script> <!-- link to js AFTER JQuery--> 
            `
        
            <!-- Import Fonts to Use -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" />
        
           
    </head>

    <body>

            <div class="overlay-navigation">
                  <nav role="navigation">
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="home.html" data-content="The beginning">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="about.html" data-content="Curious?">About</a></li>
                      <li><a href="projects.html" data-content="Showcasing my skills">Works</a></li>
                      <li><a href="resume.html" data-content="Reach out for a copy">Resume</a></li>
                      <li><a href="contact.html" data-content="Don't hesitate">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </nav>
            </div>

            <section class="home">
                  <div class="open-overlay">
                    <span class="bar-middle"></span>
                    <span class="bar-bottom"></span>
                    <span class="bar-top"></span>
                  </div>
            </section>
    </body>


</html>
```

I have a css file named "style.css"

This is my js file titled "script.js"

```js
$('.open-overlay').click(function() {
  var overlay_navigation = $('.overlay-navigation'),
    nav_item_1 = $('nav li:nth-of-type(1)'),
    nav_item_2 = $('nav li:nth-of-type(2)'),
    nav_item_3 = $('nav li:nth-of-type(3)'),
    nav_item_4 = $('nav li:nth-of-type(4)'),
    nav_item_5 = $('nav li:nth-of-type(5)'),
    top_bar = $('.bar-top'),
    middle_bar = $('.bar-middle'),
    bottom_bar = $('.bar-bottom');

  overlay_navigation.toggleClass('overlay-active');
  if (overlay_navigation.hasClass('overlay-active')) {

    top_bar.removeClass('animate-out-top-bar').addClass('animate-top-bar');
    middle_bar.removeClass('animate-out-middle-bar').addClass('animate-middle-bar');
    bottom_bar.removeClass('animate-out-bottom-bar').addClass('animate-bottom-bar');
    overlay_navigation.removeClass('overlay-slide-up').addClass('overlay-slide-down')
    nav_item_1.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-reverse').addClass('slide-in-nav-item');
    nav_item_2.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-1-reverse').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-1');
    nav_item_3.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-2-reverse').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-2');
    nav_item_4.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-3-reverse').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-3');
    nav_item_5.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-4-reverse').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-4');
  } else {
    top_bar.removeClass('animate-top-bar').addClass('animate-out-top-bar');
    middle_bar.removeClass('animate-middle-bar').addClass('animate-out-middle-bar');
    bottom_bar.removeClass('animate-bottom-bar').addClass('animate-out-bottom-bar');
    overlay_navigation.removeClass('overlay-slide-down').addClass('overlay-slide-up')
    nav_item_1.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-reverse');
    nav_item_2.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-1').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-1-reverse');
    nav_item_3.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-2').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-2-reverse');
    nav_item_4.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-3').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-3-reverse');
    nav_item_5.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-4').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-4-reverse');
  }
})
```

ANY help would be appreciated!! Thank you!!

here is what it shows: 
[image]

Comment: You're trying to attach a listeners to elements before they've been populated in the HTML, so it fails. Give your script tag the `defer` attribute so that it runs only once the document is parsed. `<script src="script.js" defer>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your js files should go at the bottom of the body. You are referencing dom elements in your js that do not exist yet because they have not been loaded in the markup.

Move your jquery and js references to the bottom of the body

Comment: I moved my references so they are the last thing before the closing body tag. However, Brackets still gives me an error in my script.js file saying that $ is not defined. Does this matter? I ran it and it runs fine when I launch the html file on chrome, but the errors won't go away. Any idea why?

Comment: @Shania your js file needs to open with the jQuery reference `$( document ).ready(function() {`, which tells is to wait until jQuery has fully loaded before running. The broswer is telling you that `$` is undefined because it's the first character in your custom script, and jQuery has not finished loading by that time.

Comment: Yes, I had that earlier in my js file but that didn't cause the errors to go away so I removed it. I added it back just now and the errors are still there. See my new edit with the modified js file

Comment: Did you close the `document.ready` function at the end of your custom script? You need to include `});`

Comment: try removing the space in between the opening `(` and `document`

Comment: I removed the space and no luck :( All the errors say "ERROR: '$' is not defined. [no-undef]" That has to mean that there is a problem with linking the JQuery still?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172829/discussion-between-a-tom-called-stu-and-shania).